# Вместо NULL в базу заносится пустое значение

Tags: php, база-данных, cakephp

Добрый день!Помогите пожалуйста.
У меня в веб-приложении на cakephp есть функция (add)для добавления проекта,то есть в базу вносится еще одна строка в таблице,проблема состоит в том, что при заполнении формы для нового проекта незаполненные поля в базу вносятся как пустое значение, хоть и было поставленно условие:

```
if(empty($this->request->data['Offer_Faktura_LBU']['kommentar'])) {
    $this->request->data['Offer_Faktura_LBU']['kommentar'] = null;
            }               
            $this->Offer_Faktura_LBU->save($this->request->data);
```

Парадокс состоит в том, что когда я добавила новый проект, и хочу его изменить(функция edit), то при сохранении на этот раз пустые поля меняются на null.
Где кроется ошибка не понятно,может в библиотеке CAKE в функции save?

Comment: Возможно что save имеет функцию, превращающую логические нули в пустые строки.
Ещё некоторые языки не всегда выводят логические значения.
Или может генерирующая функция save(и почему не add?) игнорирует пустые поля, и у вас отключены предупреждения (Например, отсутствует ключ массива) в этом случае ничего нигде писаться не будет.
Если очень хочется предлагаю написать:

foreach($this->request->data['Offer_Faktura_LBU'] as $key=>$val)

{

if(empty($val)) $this->request->data['Offer_Faktura_LBU'][$key] = 'NULL';

}

(Собственно, экранировать значение как строковую а не логическую переменную.)

Comment: спасибо за ответ, выше я и описывала функцию add. Дело в том что есть еще функция edit,которая изменяеет введенные значения,и при вызове этой функции пустые поля (незаполненные в add)преобразуются в NULL.То есть функция SAVE все таки выводит логические нули но почему то только в EDIT а не в ADD.Может тут как то функция SAVE читает NULL только при повторной записи поля таблицы?Хотя обе функции практически индентичны

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте не указывать :

```
if(empty($this->request->data['Offer_Faktura_LBU']['kommentar'])) {
    $this->request->data['Offer_Faktura_LBU']['kommentar'] = null;
}    
$this->Offer_Faktura_LBU->save($this->request->data);
```

А сделайте просто (логика ведь останется та же):

```
    $this->Offer_Faktura_LBU->save($this->request->data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Я, к примеру, использую этот плагин для cakephp 2.x
[CakePHP-NullableBehavior](https://github.com/robwilkerson/CakePHP-NullableBehavior)
Тоже искал решение этой проблемы и наткнулся на это решение, теперь у меня вместо пустых строк сохраняется NULL